# Converting Celcius to Fahrenheit - Double.TryParse

Tags: c#

I have a successful clean code that does a conversion of Celcius to Fahrenheit using Double.Parse. However, I was curious on how it would look if I did a Double.TryParse but I can't seem to figure out how to complete the code. Once executed, I am able to present "Invalid Code", in my "if, else" but I still get this after my Invaild Output...

> Please enter a value for conversion: 
>   30x 
>   Invalid code 
>   The conversion from Celcius to Fahrenheit is: 32

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace CSharpBasics
{
    class Program
    {
        public static double CelciusToFarenheit(string celciusTemperature)
        {
            //Converting string to a double for conversion

            double celcius;
            if (Double.TryParse(celciusTemperature, out celcius))
            {

            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid code");
            }
            double fahrenheit = (celcius * 9 / 5) + 32;
            return fahrenheit;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for conversion:");
            var input = CelciusToFarenheit(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The conversion from Celcius to Fahrenheit is: " + input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint 1: a code-smell - an empty `if` block. Hint 2: when are you calculating the fahrenheit value?. Tip: investigate `Nullable<double>` as return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify your input before the conversion to make sure you never display invalid result for an invalid input but return a message notifying the wrong input first. Something like this:

```
    public static double CelciusToFarenheit(double celcius)
    {
        double fahrenheit = (celcius * 9 / 5) + 32;
        return fahrenheit;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for conversion:");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        double celcius;
        if (Double.TryParse(input, out celcius))
        {
            var result = CelciusToFarenheit(celcius);
            Console.WriteLine("The conversion from Celcius to Fahrenheit is: " + result);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid code");
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly how I was picturing it to be. Similar to my Double.Parse. I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to add the TryParse in the Main Method.

Comment: @Loves2Program: IMHO it's not appropriate. The level of abstraction in the main method is too low. There is now almost no point in having the actual calculation in its own method, especially if you make that method a one liner like `public double Fahrenheit(double celsius) => celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;`

Answer (score 0):

The method signature `public static double CelciusToFarenheit(...)` says that this method returns a value - and currently it does.

However, your program flow has to consider invalid input - and thus you need 2 information:

1. was the entered value a valid value
2. what's *is* the value

There are different methods to solve this issue, at least the following:

1. return a struct or object that holds both information
2. use the return value and indicate invalid results with exceptions
3. split the single method into 2 methods, one for checking validity and one for delivering the value.

Let's discuss the 3 options:

- 3) This might be looking nice, but when you look at `Double.TryParse()`, you'll likely introduce duplicate code. And when you look at the `Main` method, the abstraction level will not be the same.
- 2) Exceptions shall be used for exceptional cases. Wrong user input seems to be a rather usual thing. Not ideal for this case.
- 1) Sounds quite ok, except that the method might be responsible for 2 things: checking validity and calculating.

To implement that, you don't even need to write a new struct or class. You can simply use `Nullable<double>` or `double?`.

Since you're talking about clean code (potentially referring to R.C. Martin), I would start by looking at the main method. Basically I would say the code follows the IPO principle (input, processing, output). However, one line does 2 things:

```
var input = CelciusToFarenheit(Console.ReadLine());
```

Also, the variable name `input` is not so useful here, because it's not the input of the user, but the output after processing.

Proposal for that part:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var userInput = GetCelsiusInputFromUser();
    var output = CelciusToFarenheit(userInput);
    PrintOutput(output);
}
```

Also, the conversion method does not only convert, but print partial results as well:

```
Console.WriteLine("Invalid code");
```

I'd remove that piece and leave it to the output method to handle that case.

Full code:

```
using System;

namespace CSharpBasics
{
    class Program
    {
        public static double? CelciusToFarenheit(string celciusTemperature)
        {
            //Converting string to a double for conversion
            double celcius;
            if (Double.TryParse(celciusTemperature, out celcius))
            {
                double fahrenheit = (celcius * 9 / 5) + 32;
                return fahrenheit;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var userInput = GetCelsiusInputFromUser();
            var output = CelciusToFarenheit(userInput);
            PrintOutput(output);
        }

        private static void PrintOutput(double? output)
        {
            if (output == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid code");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The conversion from Celcius to Fahrenheit is: " + output);
            }
        }

        private static string GetCelsiusInputFromUser()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a celsius value for conversion:");
            var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            return userInput;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: if you don't have a technical issue, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be better suited for questions regarding clean code.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'll check it out.